Give untrusted remote user read access to encrypted home folder
Say I'd like to provide an immutable offsite backup service for customers by installing a NAS at their site that will periodically update (weekly) rsync/syncthing jobs to my site where I'll rotate air-gapped backups on an A/B basis (A spun-down, powered off while B drives run per month);
I'd like to enforce encryption so I can't see their stuff, then I'll use Linux encrypted home folders (LUKS or encryptfs?) on the NAS with a remote access backup user for me that just sucks up the raw scrambled files. They will therefore leave the building encrypted in a way the transport does not understand and I can use unencrypted disks my end.
I will be able to know the number of files, size, mod-dates etc but not the contents yes? Using encrypt-fs or LUKS?
I will be able to reboot my servers because I do not use encryption on the already encrypted files.
If the customer reboots their NAS... will they need to type a password to un-brick the setup? I guess that is implementation specific and up to them. Open Media Vault is what I am currently using, I guess they are likely to use Mac/Win more than Linux.
It would need a stored password to unlock the user folder if the NAS reboots? Then my remote-backup user can see or not see this?
Is there a software that does this thing better than my home-bake style?

In most interpretations immutable means something like write once, cannot be changed or overwritten anymore so how does that relate to your A/B scheme for reusing drives? Because currently your description seems like a snake-oil version of a very common and regular off-site copy of on-premise backups.

It relates in that it would be a poor-mans version of what normally costs quite a lot - for example Rubrik / Veeam both do not display prices so I know it's pricey. It would make incremental backups impossible but the trustless backup agent would only see encrypted files prior to moving them offsite to my site, then onto a tape library.
